# CSS: Hover a HTML submit button

Tags: html, css, button, submit

I'm trying to style a HTML submit button in CSS:

HTML:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Yes" id="popUpYes">
```

CSS:

```css
#popUpYes
{
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
#popUpYes:hover
{
  background-color: white;
}
```

The basic style works but the background does not change color on hover.

Comment: Just a warning to anyone reading... for me this problem appears to occur when using the Chrome 'device preview' - this is expected... your finger does not have a hover state on mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code works for me.  Be sure you don't have any other conflicting styles inherited by the submit button.

Answer (score 3):

Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg228/2/)

Try this:

```css
#popUpYes {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  /* SET COLOR IN WHITE */
}

#popUpYes:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* SET COLOR IN BLACK */
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Yes" id="popUpYes">
```

You have to assign the `color` - attribute for the text.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in Chrome and it worked.

```css
#popUpYes {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

#popUpYes:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Yes" id="popUpYes">
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is now working -> http://jsfiddle.net/2wYqd/ What is your browser?

```css
#popUpYes {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
}
#popUpYes:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working fine [link](http://jsbin.com/idEkaXE/2/edit)

```css
#popUpYes {
   width: 60px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: black;
   color:white;
}
#popUpYes:hover {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question "The basic style works but the background does not change color on hover." , this happens only when you set your BackColor or background-color through properties. your code works fine because you have used css class instead of properties.

Answer (score 0):

*My work may be of use to you in this regard.*

```css
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #42b72a;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid #42b72a;
  width: 200px;
}

#kayitol:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0099ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

input[type=reset] {
  background-color: #FF8A80;
  color: white;
  border: 5px solid #FF8A80;
  width: 120px;
}

#iptal:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FF3C41;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="kayitol" value="Kayıt Ol">
<input type="reset" id="iptal" value="Vaz Geçtim">
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information as to why this would be the answer to the question. What does the code do etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).